# Update the graph in Ford-Fulkerson

Tags: java, graph, ford-fulkerson

I'm implementing the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm but i have some problem in updating the graph after augmenting phase. My data structure doesn't make this easy i guess.

To represent the graph i use this:

```
private Map<Vertex, ArrayList<Edge>> outgoingEdges;
```

That is, i associate at each Vertex its list of outgoing edges.

To manage the backward edges, i associated a "opposite" edge for each edge in the graph.

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

```
public class FF {

    /**
     * Associates each Vertex with his list of outgoing edges
     */
    private Map<Vertex, ArrayList<Edge>> outgoingEdges;

    public FF() {
        outgoingEdges = new HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Edge>>();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the nodes of the graph
     */ 
    public Collection<Vertex> getNodes() {
        return outgoingEdges.keySet();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the outgoing edges of a node
     */
    public Collection<Edge> getIncidentEdges(Vertex v) {
        return outgoingEdges.get(v);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new edge to the graph
     */
    public void insertEdge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, float capacity) throws Exception {
        if (!(outgoingEdges.containsKey(source) && outgoingEdges.containsKey(destination)))
            throw new Exception("Unable to add the edge");

        Edge e = new Edge(source, destination, capacity);
        Edge opposite = new Edge(destination, source, capacity);
        outgoingEdges.get(source).add(e);
        outgoingEdges.get(destination).add(opposite);
        e.setOpposite(opposite);
        opposite.setOpposite(e);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new node to the graph
     */
    public void insertNode(Vertex v) {
        if (!outgoingEdges.containsKey(v))
            outgoingEdges.put(v, new ArrayList<Edge>());
    }

    /**
     * Ford-Fulkerson algorithm
     * 
     * @return max flow
     */
    public int fordFulkerson(Vertex source, Vertex destination) {
        List<Edge> path = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        int maxFlow = 0;
        while(bfs(source, destination, path)) {
            // finds the bottleneck
            float minCap = bottleneck(path);
            // updates the maxFlow
            maxFlow += minCap;            
            // updates the graph <-- this updates only the local list path, not the graph!
            for(Edge e : path) {
                try {
                    e.addFlow(minCap);
                    e.getOpposite().addFlow(-minCap);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            path.clear();
        }
        return maxFlow;
    } 

    /**
     * @param Path of which we have to find the bottleneck
     * @return bottleneck of the path
     */
    private float bottleneck(List<Edge> path) {
        float min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(Edge e : path) {
            float capacity = e.getCapacity();
            if(capacity <= min) {
                min = capacity;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    /**
     * BFS to obtain a path from the source to the destination
     * 
     * @param source 
     * @param destination
     * @param path
     * @return
     */
    private boolean bfs(Vertex source, Vertex destination, List<Edge> path) {
        Queue<Vertex> queue = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        List<Vertex> visited = new ArrayList<Vertex>(); // list of visited vertexes
        queue.add(source);
        //source.setVisited(true);
        visited.add(source);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex d = queue.remove();
            if(!d.equals(destination)) {
                ArrayList<Edge> d_outgoingEdges = outgoingEdges.get(d);
                for(Edge e : d_outgoingEdges) {
                    if(e.getCapacity() - e.getFlow() > 0) { // there is still available flow
                        Vertex u = e.getDestination();
                        if(!visited.contains(u)) {
                            //u.setVisited(true);
                            visited.add(u);
                            queue.add(u);
                            path.add(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(visited.contains(destination)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edge**

```
public class Edge {

    private Vertex source;
    private Vertex destination;
    private float flow;
    private final float capacity;
    private Edge opposite;

    public Edge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, float capacity) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public Edge getOpposite() {
        return opposite;
    }

    public void setOpposite(Edge e) {
        opposite = e;
    }

    public void setSource(Vertex v) {
        source = v;
    }

    public void setDestination(Vertex v) {
        destination = v;
    }

    public void addFlow(float f) throws Exception {
        if(flow == capacity) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to add flow");
        }
        flow += f;
    }

    public Vertex getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public Vertex getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public float getFlow() {
        return flow;
    }

    public float getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Edge e = (Edge)o;
        return e.getSource().equals(this.getSource()) &&       e.getDestination().equals(this.getDestination());
    }
}
```

**Vertex**

```
public class Vertex {

    private String label;

    public Vertex(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Vertex v = (Vertex)o;
        return v.getLabel().equals(this.getLabel());
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, the concept of associating each edge with an "opposite" edge is the usual way to go here (although implementation details may vary). Can you describe the "problem" more elaborately? Is it related to the comment `this updates only the local list...`? This should not be the case, since it seems like *references* of edges are used everywhere, and no new edges are created. In doubt, insert a `printDebugInfo` method that prints all edges and their flows, and call this method after each update step (using a small graph, so that you can easily verify the output with pen+paper)

Comment: So for you the code is ok? Is it a good implementation? Right now, if i start the program, it never ends. However, i'll do what you say. PS: sei italiano?

Comment: From a first glance, the code looks OK, but I did not try it or read it in *all* detail - I just wanted to know what the actual problem is. One could consider to separate the graph structure and the algorithm, but recommendations like this would rather fit to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . But there is one potential problem....

Comment: The potential problem: It seems like you are never clearing the "visited" flags of the nodes, by calling `node.setVisited(false)` on all nodes. If it runs forever, a debug output (as mentioned above) might already be helpful. If not, try to create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (with main method and a small example graph).

Comment: Ok i modified the BFS. Now the program terminates but returns 0... uhmmm. I'll put the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, strictly speaking, the question could be considered as being "Off topic" (since you're mainly looking for debugging help), this is one of your first questions, so some general hints:

---

When you post a question here, consider that people here a volunteers. Make it **easy** for them to answer the question. In this particular case: You should create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that people can quickly copy & paste your code (preferably, in a single code block) and run the program without any effort. For example, you should include a test class, inculding a `main` method, like this one:

```
public class FFTest
{
    /**
     *     B---D
     *    / \ / \
     *   A   .   F
     *    \ / \ /
     *     C---E
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        FF ff = new FF();

        Vertex vA = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex vB = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex vC = new Vertex("C");
        Vertex vD = new Vertex("D");
        Vertex vE = new Vertex("E");
        Vertex vF = new Vertex("F");
        ff.insertNode(vA);
        ff.insertNode(vB);
        ff.insertNode(vC);
        ff.insertNode(vD);
        ff.insertNode(vE);
        ff.insertNode(vF);

        ff.insertEdge(vA, vB, 3.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vA, vC, 2.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vB, vD, 1.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vB, vE, 4.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vC, vD, 2.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vC, vE, 1.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vD, vF, 2.0f);
        ff.insertEdge(vE, vF, 1.0f);

        float result = ff.fordFulkerson(vA, vF);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

(You should already have created such a test class when you write the question, anyhow!)

---

You should make clear that you are **NOT** using StackOverflow as a "magic problem solving machine". In this case: I already mentioned that you should include *debug outputs*. If you had extended your `FF` class with methods like these....

```
private static void printPath(List<Edge> path)
{
    System.out.println("Path: ");
    for (int i=0; i<path.size(); i++)
    {
        Edge e = path.get(i);
        System.out.println(
            "Edge "+e+
            " flow "+e.getFlow()+
            " cap "+e.getCapacity());
    }
}
```

which can be called in the main loop like this:

```
    while(bfs(source, destination, path)) {
        ...
        System.out.println("Before updating with "+minCap);
        printPath(path);

        // updates the maxFlow
        ....

        System.out.println("After  updating with "+minCap);
        printPath(path);

        ...
    }
```

then you would already have noticed the main problem with your code: ...

---

The `bfs` method is wrong! You are **not** properly reconstructing the *path* that led you to the destination vertex. Instead, you are adding every visited vertex to the path. You have to track which edge was used for reaching a particular node, and when you reached the destination vertex, have to go backward.

A quick-and-dirty approach could *roughly(!)*  look like this:

```
private boolean bfs(Vertex source, Vertex destination, List<Edge> path) {
    Queue<Vertex> queue = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    List<Vertex> visited = new ArrayList<Vertex>(); // list of visited vertexes
    queue.add(source);
    visited.add(source);
    Map<Vertex, Edge> predecessorEdges = new HashMap<Vertex, Edge>();
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex d = queue.remove();
        if(!d.equals(destination)) {
            ArrayList<Edge> d_outgoingEdges = outgoingEdges.get(d);
            for(Edge e : d_outgoingEdges) {
                if(e.getCapacity() - e.getFlow() > 0) { // there is still available flow
                    Vertex u = e.getDestination();
                    if(!visited.contains(u)) {
                        visited.add(u);
                        queue.add(u);
                        predecessorEdges.put(u, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            constructPath(destination, predecessorEdges, path);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void constructPath(Vertex destination,
    Map<Vertex, Edge> predecessorEdges, List<Edge> path)
{
    Vertex v = destination;
    while (true)
    {
        Edge e = predecessorEdges.get(v);
        if (e == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        path.add(0, e);
        v = e.getSource();
    }
}
```

(You should *always* test such a central method independently. You could have easily created a small test program that computes several paths, and you would quickly have noticed that these paths are wrong - and thus, that the Ford Fulkerson can't work properly at all).

---

Further remarks:

Whenever you override the `equals` method, you must also override the `hashCode` method. Some rules apply here, you should **definitely** refer to the [documentation of `Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`Object#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).

It is often beneficial to additionally override the `toString` method, so that you may easily print the objects to the console.

In your case, these methods could be implemented like this, for `Vertex`

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return getLabel().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Vertex v = (Vertex)o;
    return v.getLabel().equals(this.getLabel());
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return getLabel();
}
```

And for `Edge`

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "("+getSource()+","+getDestination()+")";
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return source.hashCode() ^ destination.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Edge e = (Edge)o;
    return e.getSource().equals(this.getSource()) &&       
        e.getDestination().equals(this.getDestination());
}
```

The capacities of the edges are `float` values, so the resulting flow should also be a `float` value.

With the modifications mentioned above, the program runs and prints a "plausible" result. I have **NOT** verified it for correctness. But this is your task, and it should be much easier now.

---

P.S: No, io sono tedesco.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My next question will be better than this, i promise. Now it returns a flow, a wrong flow, but that's something. I used your print methot to debug, and seems that the flow on an edge can exceed his capacity!

Comment: @user3075478 The "bottleneck" method only uses the *capacity*. But it should return the minimum "capacity-flow" of all edges. (Parts of the capacity may already be "occupied" by a certain flow, and this is not considered yet). But you'll probably figure this out.

Comment: I can fix it ;) I need to make this  algorithm as faster as possible too, because it must works with VERY BIG graphs. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: There are some libraries that already offer implementations of FordFulkerson, and probably of other MaxFlow-Algorithms (that may even be more efficient for large graphs!). But this would imply a "Library Recommendation", and this would **definitiely** be off-topic for StackOverflow....

Comment: I need to implement it by myself, without libraries ;)